# Time complexity with fixed numbers

Tags: c, time-complexity

Suppose I have an array:
`int a[] = {1, 4, 7, 3}, n = 4;` 
I define: `int x = a[1], y = a[2];` (This is completely random, there is no meaning to the numbers or the indexes).
Is the following program `O(n)`, since `y-x` is some fixed number? What if `y-x > n`, when `n` is the length of the array?

```
 for (int i=0; i<=y-x; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
         // something
     }
 }
```

Comment: Depending on compiler, `something`, can be O(1). Provide a [mcve]. But then: we are no "do my homework" site.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity will be `O(n*(y-x))`.

`x` and `y` are arbitrary values (chosen from the array) and they have no relation to `n`.